# 404 erros and issues with manifest.json when deploying React App to github pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, create-react-app, github-pages

Getting the following error when trying to deploy to gitub pages. React app used to create app.

```
GET https://wrecket.github.io/Wrecket/gmcb-react-conversion-new/static/css/2.038644eb.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
manifest.json:1 GET https://wrecket.github.io/Wrecket/gmcb-react-conversion-new/manifest.json 404
```

Relatively new to React and cant work it out. This is my package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "gmcb-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Wrecket/gmcb-react-conversion-new/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^1.7.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "save-dev": "0.0.1-security",
    "tachyons": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Going insane trying to work this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the homepage path :
`"homepage": "https://yourusername.github.io/your-project-name",`

Comment: Thank you, I worked this out shortly after posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake in the homepage link as mentioned in the answer above, try to correct this mistake and check this article for better understanding [link](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f)